# Asbestos or normal insulation within hot water tank

Tags: asbestos

I was removing my hot water tank and realised there was some kind of insulation inside. Does this look like asbestos?

[image]

this is the material. My initial thoughts were fibreglass. Can anyone ascertain what the material is?

Comment: Age of the tank? Only way to be sure about asbestos is lab testing. Looks the same in pictures as other stuff.

Comment: There are a lot of testing labs that will tell you within a week, but it will likely cost multiple tens of dollars.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the only way to know if something is asbestos is to have it lab tested. Even at the lab they can't tell just by looking at it.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to know if its asbestos or not is by testing it.  There are test kits you can buy at your local hardware store, these test kits require that you mail out the sample.  You can also Google "Asbestos testing center near me" their may also be a physical place you could take a sample to yourself.

If you take it to a physical location:
-put on a mask and gloves
-Put a sample in a zip-loc bag
-double seal that bag inside another zip-loc bag

If you buy a testing kit the directions will be similar.

Ive tested 7-10 differnt things in my own house that I thought was asbestos and they all came back as not asbestos and some other material.

Its really better to test than not test if youre worried about it.  Always good to have peace of mind.  Best of luck!

Comment: You can also tell by age of the tank.